# How can I customize the New Backlog Items menu to include 'Areas'?

Tags: tfs

How can I customize the following screen to have a title and an Areas dropdown?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the witadmin command-line tool, and do an exportprocessconfig, then modify the xml and do an importprocessconfig.

Docs on the witadmin tool are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236914.aspx

In the ProcessConfig.xml you can modify which fields are shown:

[image]

Comment: I'm not really seeing where in that xml file I can change the items in the 'New' quick entry screen.

Comment: Look at my screenshot, it's the add panel block under each backlog